# How to config Glide for download image file with Bearer token Authentication?

Tags: java, android, api, authentication, android-glide

I want to download image from authentication API. How to download config Glide?

```
GlideUrl glideUrl = new GlideUrl(url,
new LazyHeaders.Builder()
    .addHeader("Authorization", token)
    .build());

GlideApp.with(context) 
        .load(glideUrl)
         .into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)` instead.